# DRY (refactor) this code that uses callbacks?

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I have several methods that have a return type `IEnumerable<T>`. These methods are part of `DomainService` class, and on the client they are generated with a return type of `InvokeOperation<T>`

```
public InvokeOperation<IEnumerable<T>> MethodA(string prm, Action<InvokeOperation<IEnumerable<T>>> 

public InvokeOperation<IEnumerable<T>> MethodB(Action<InvokeOperation<IEnumerable<T>>>
```

WHen calling these methods, the code in the callback is basically the same

```
void SomeMethodA(string someString, Action<ResultsArgs<string>> operationCompleted)
{
    MyContext.MethodA(someString, c =>
        {
            // same code (operationCompleted parameter is used)
        }, null);
}

void SomeMethodA(Action<ResultsArgs<string>> operationCompleted)
{
    MyContext.MethodB(c =>
        {
            // same code (operationCompleted parameter is used)
        }, null);
}
```

How can I refactor this so there is no duplicate code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a method that takes a c and operationCompleted....

then

```
  MyContext.MethodA(someString, c => MyShinyNewMethod(c, operationCompleted), null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just extract a method that take a `InvokeOperation<IEnumerable<T>>` and a `Action<ResultsArgs<string>>` as parameters. And then call the method in the `c => { }`.

```
void SomeMethodA(string someString, Action<ResultsArgs<string>> operationCompleted)
{
    MyContext.MethodA(someString, c =>
        {
            NewMethod(c, operationCompleted);
        }, null);
}

void SomeMethodA(string someString, Action<ResultsArgs<string>> operationCompleted)
{
    MyContext.MethodB(c =>
        {
            NewMethod(c, operationCompleted);
        }, null);
}
```